# Using Airflow to Run .bat file or PowerShell program located in remote Windows Box

Tags: airflow, windows-task-scheduler

Currently some of the jobs are running in different Windows VM's.
for eg.,
Task Scheduler to run

- Powershell files
- .bat files
- python files.

Sql Agent jobs

- To run SSIS packages

We are planning to use Airflow to trigger all these jobs to have better visibility and manage dependencies.

Our Airflow in Ubuntu.

I would like know if there is any way to trigger above mentioned jobs in Windows via Airflow.

Can I get some examples on how to achieve my objectives? Please suggest what packages/libraries/plugins/operators I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. I would start by looking into the winrm operator and hook that you find in under Microsoft in providers:
http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-winrm/stable/index.html

and maybe also:
https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm